# SFML graphics Draw Texture in Window- Black Screen

Tags: c++, sfml

I just tried to write a chess engine, and what is important to me is that I get a nice visual representation of the game. I tried to implement the Code in a Visual Studio project - the problem is that the program only shows me a black screen instead of the texture I loaded.

My Code is the following:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <time.h>
using namespace sf;

int main(){

    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(1000, 1000), "MattseChess!");

    Texture t1;
    t1.loadFromFile("images/board.png");
    Sprite s(t1);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        Event e;

        while (window.pollEvent(e)) {

            if (e.type == Event::Closed)
                window.close();
    //Draw
            window.clear();
            window.draw(s);
            window.display();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Do you have any idea of what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to put your drawing code **outside** your event loop. Otherwise you're only drawing whenever there's some event happening (such as cursor movement).

Comment: It is still not working, just tried it out. Could it be that it  is not working with Visual Studio or that you need some special compiling setttings? I compiled via x64 instead of x86 because the .dlls were also compiled with x64, which threw an error before.

Now, so far no compiling errors or anything else, just a clean black window.

Answer (score 0):

That code works. I am pretty sure you did not put your board.png into the images directory in your execution path.

Make sure this image is available:

```
t1.loadFromFile("images/board.png");
```

Comment: It definitely is! One idea i had is that the programm actually loads the texture, but puts it into a very weird spot "outside" of the window so i do not see it. Is that possible?

Comment: No way. SFML puts it on 0/0 of the window. It is a PNG and the first black checkerboard field is black and filling the whole screen?